# Using Regex in C# to parse a string into an array/list by delimiter with one delimiter exception

Tags: c#, regex

My input string:

```
var s = "{1, >, [4,6,7,8], a, b, [x,y], d, 9}";
```

I'd like to remove the **{}** and get an array with each element separated by a comma EXCEPT when the comma is inside **[]** -- basically anything in brackets will be returned as its own element without the brackets.

Desired output **List< String >** or **String[]** whose contents are:

```
1
>
4,6,7,8
a
b
x,y
d
9
```

ETA:  Here is my UnitText (xunit), which tests each of the patterns suggested by @washington-guedes, with a parameter to trim the input string of whitespaces.  The test fails on both cases when the WS is cleaned.

```
    [Theory]
    [InlineData(@"([^{\s]+(?=(?:,|})))", false)]
    [InlineData(@"([^{\s]+(?=(?:,|})))", true)]
    [InlineData(@"([^{\s[\]]+(?=(?:]|,|})))", false)]
    [InlineData(@"([^{\s[\]]+(?=(?:]|,|})))", true)]
    public void SO(string pattern, bool trimWS)
    {
        //Arrange
        var exp = "{1, >, [4,6,7,8], a, b, [x,y], d, 9}";
        if (trimWS)
            exp = exp.Replace(" ", "");
        Match match = Regex.Match(exp, pattern);
        var list = new List<String>();
        while (match.Success)
        {
            list.Add(match.Value);
            match = match.NextMatch();
        }
        Assert.Equal(8, list.Count);
    }
```

Comment: Can sets of `[...]` be nested? And are there always spaces between the different major elements? Because right now, it seems like you can just remove the starting `'{'` and ending `'}'`, split by `", "`, and then remove any `'['`s and `']'`s.

Comment: What have you tried? I'm glad to help, but StackExchange isn't a coding service, you're not supposed to say "here's my problem, go solve it." Instead, show us your proposed solution and we can help you refine it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this Regex:

```
((?<=,\[)[^]]+)|((?<={)[^,}]+)|((?<=,)(?!\[)[^,}]+)
```

---

[Regex live here.](https://regex101.com/r/bN3gE8/5)

Explaining:

```
(                  # start of capturing group
  (?<=,\[)         # starting with ",["
  [^]]+            # matches all till next "]"
)                  # end of capturing group

  |                # OR

(
    (?<={)         # starting with "{"
    [^,}]+         # matches all till next "," or "}"
)

  |                # OR

(
    (?<=,)(?!\[)   # starting with "," and not a "["
    [^,}]+         # matches all till next "," or "}"
)
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Regex101 says that this specifically has a non-capturing group, which doesn't seem very useful... shouldn't there be capturing groups in there somewhere?

Comment: `([^{\s]+(?=(?:,|})))` might work best - it's got the capture groups to make an array.

Comment: This matches fairly well, however is there a way to ignore whitespace?

Comment: If you  `s = s.Replace(" ", "");` before calling the regex, it returns a different set of matches

Comment: That works great.  I was also looking for the version that included **{}**. I wish I could "read" your expression to understand it.  I pasted that expression in regex101.  Is the first "part" of the expression that you just added `((?<=,\[)[^]]+)`